# Eclipse IDE 2020-12 R Packages (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers), Apache Tomcat Version 9 not appearing on server list

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9

I have already installed the software "JST Server Adapter" and "JST Server Adapter Extensions" but Tomcat version 9 still does not appear on the server list. The latest version available is version 8.0

Eclipse version: 2020-12 R, IDE for Java Developers

Apache Tomcat: Version 9

I have already tried removing "JST Server Adapter" but that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Which version of JST Server Adapter Extensions did you install? Did you install it from the 2020-12 update site?

Comment: @nitind I installed it from the "Install New Software..." option in Eclipse.

The version number is: 3.3.302.v201501040116

Comment: You should be seeing a v2020 datestamp in the version if it's the right one. Check for updates or reinstall it using the 2020-12 update site: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12 or https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest .

Comment: @nitind When I reinstalled the latest version they had the same number, but now it works, even up to version 10. 
Thank you!